# ARM STM32 simulator like proteous and some good book to start with?

Tags: arm, stm32, simulation

I want to get my hand dirty with ARM programming. I have 8051/PIC16F/PIC18F programing experience. I searched about ARM and find STM32 series cheap. But before buying i want to get handy with it via some kind of simulator similar to proteous from [labcenter.com](http://www.labcenter.com/index.cfm). I searched about it but could not find any thing useful. Could some one please refer me to some good simulation based development environment for ARM preferably STM32 series. Thanks

Comment: You can get a simulator for an arm core of various varieties, but probably not for all the peripherals.  STM32 isn't one device, its a family spanning at least three cores (Cortex M3, M0, and M4), and numerous slight peripheral variations - which one do you need?   At $10, just get one of the boards and try the real thing.  Where you need to test program logic, cross compile for your development machine.

Comment: It is very difficult to find ARM in my local market(Pakistan) I have to import it and I have no idea about it. So before importing I want to get complete atleast some basic learning about ARM. Any suggestion about the starting point?

Answer (score 7):

You can use Qemu for simulation. It may have an STM32 simulator inside. Or just use Proteus. I always use the free Demonstration version to play with various MCUs.

I find this ARM tutorial very helpful for me. It is created by `Miro Samek`, one of the most famous embedded guru and the author of the book `"Practical UML Statecharts in C/C++: Event-Driven Programming for Embedded Systems"`. This video series is available on youtube. You can get the link from [Miro's blog](http://embeddedgurus.com/state-space/2013/01/embedded-c-programming-with-arm-cortex-m-video-course/).

This [blog](http://www.bravegnu.org/gnu-eprog/index.html) is an excellent introduction to QEMU with ARM.